# Android Google Play Billing Library v2/v3: How to stop someone maliciously preventing an acknowledgement and therefore get their purchase refunded?

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library

I've been implementing Google Play Billing Library v3, and noticed that starting v2 we must [acknowledge a purchase after granting entitlement to the purchased feature](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process), otherwise the user is refunded within 3 days. So essentially the lifecycle is something like:

1. User purchases something, e.g. subscription to a premium account.
2. The client app sends the purchase and signature to the backend so the user is entitled to the purchase, e.g. premium account.
3. The backend responds with a success, we then acknowledge with Google Play the purchase was entitled (otherwise a refund is given).

However, that got me thinking, what is stopping a malicious user from modifying the APK (or even blocking the network call) so that the acknowledgment call is *not* made, therefore the user is refunded within 3 days, but entitlement (step 2 above) is still given. What can I do the stop this within my app? How can I make sure the acknowledgment definitely goes through if the entitlement is given?

Answer (score 0):

If no acknowledgement is made and after 3 days gets refunded, the purchased items query to the google servers will return an empty list, so you will know he is not entitled.

If a user keeps on purchasing the same item, and cancelling it due to not acknowledgement or other mechanisms, this should trigger Google alarms, and probably the user's payment method will be revoked. Google purchase system has many mechanisms in-place at server level to verify that purchases are genuine.